# It is too slow to excute query that get data from another table which has foreign key and not exists in

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

My **select** query is too slow.

### blog_data table

About 2,000,000 rows.

```
Field   Type
no      bigint(20)  primary key, auto_increment
title   text
body    text
tags    text
url     varchar(200)
date    datetime
```

### ngram_relation table

```
Field       Type
no          int     primary key, auto_increment
blogId      bigint(20)
term        varchar(200)
frequency   bigint(20)
TF          float
IDF         float
weight      float
Ns          int(11)

primary key(no),
unique key(blogid, term),
foreign key(blogId) references blog_data(no)
```

I want to get blog_data.no which is not in ngram_relation table. So, I execute query below.

```
select no, title, body, tags, url 
from blog_data where not exists (
    select blogid as gg 
    from ngram_relation 
    group by blogid 
    having blog_data.no=gg
) limit 0, 10000
```

Then, first executing was well. After first executing, The **ngram_relation** table has about **260,000** rows.

**But second executing did not work. Just lock.**

How do I modify my query?

Comment: Field `no` with type `text` and auto_increment is wrong, it must be type `int`

Comment: @Noman Oh, sorry my mistake. Fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use left outer join to filter the records that are existing in blog_data and not in ngram_relation. This should be faster.
something like this(may not be the exact code) :

```
    select top 10000
    from blog_data b
    left outer join ngram_relation n
    on b.no = n.no
    where n.no is null
```